# Do you know why this cherry-pick makes code diff?

Tags: git, cherry-pick

[image]

I made some commit (C and D) in master branch for hotfix.
After this, I cherry pick these commit in develop branch.
I guess, If I make Pull Request (base is master, compare is develop), there is no code diff.
But there is code diff which includes C and D code changes.
Can you explain why there is code diff...??

Comment: New commits but functionally no change -> there is no diff

Comment: If there were a diff, what would it be? What lines are different between `D` and `D'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cherry-picking](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) *replicates* the code changes, so the exact same code changes and commit messages would be applied but the *commit hashes* would be different because they're *new, replicated commits*.

From documentation:

> Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one introduces, recording a **new commit** for each.

Answer (score 0):

C' contains the same textual changes as C because that's how cherry pick works. So clearly if you `git diff C C'`, there will be no visible changes because they both have the exact same code. In this situation, I suggest merging master into dev instead of cherry picking. This will help avoid merge conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

On a Pull Request or a Merge Request (of Gitlab), comparing the source branch (`develop` in your case) with the target branch (`master`) is equivalent to

```
git diff master...develop
```

instead of

```
git diff master..develop
# Or
git diff master develop
```

With [3 dots](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203-1) `...`, it's comparing `b` with `D'`. `b` is the merge-base (or fork-point) of `master` and `develop`.

With 2 dots `..` or no dots, it's comparing `D` and `D'`, which is what you expect.

From the view of a Pull Request or a Merge Request, it focuses on the changes which have been made since the fork-point, the contribution on `develop`.

Here is [a Gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/15140#note_11709832) that explains the situation.