# Git Cherry pick is showing already committed code as part of PR

Tags: git, github, git-cherry-pick

I am using GitHub.
Lets consider we have a two branches **dev** and **qa**. At this point both my dev and qa branch are in sync (dev and qa has no difference). I have modified/modified some code in feature_dev (created from dev branch). I have created Pull Request from feature_dev to dev and merged it, the commit id generated for that PR merge is e105xfb. At this point the only difference between dev and qa branch is the new commit e105xfb.

Now I checkout out to qa branch and ran git pull command. Now I have used the below command

```
git cherry-pick -m 1 -x e105xfb
```

This will cherry pick the commit e105xfb. Now I have pushed it to **qa**. **At this point both the qa and dev are in sync again.**

Now If I raise PR from dev to qa , My expectation is that it should display the  message "**There is nothing to compare**", but it is showing the files modified/added during the commit e105xfb as files changed.

Can someone explain this behaviour and How to resolve it?

Comment: I once gave an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76942066/6330106) to a similar question. The diff in a PR from the source branch to the target branch is from the merge-base of the source branch and the target branch to the target branch, not from the source branch to the target branch. Only when the source branch is exactly right the merge-base, the 2 kinds of diffs are the same.

Comment: Why cherry-picking the merge commit? "*At this point the only difference between dev and qa branch is the new commit e105xfb*" Only a merge commit and no other commits? Sounds odd.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question lies in how merges and cherry-picks work in Git.

The cherry-pick command introduces the changes of a given commit, meaning that it re-applies the same set of modifications included in the commit. It doesn't "copy" the commit, but it rather creates a new one with the same modifications.

As the official documentation states:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

> apply the change each one introduces, recording a new commit for each.

Instead, when merging two branches, Git looks for their closest common ancestor and marks it as the merge basis. This particular commit (the merge basis) is used as the starting point of the merge, and on top of it, Git applies every subsequent commit defined on the merging branches.

When you attempt to merge `dev` into `qa`, Git determines their closest common ancestor and applies every difference introduced after it. In your case, the set of differences corresponds to: the merge commit on the `dev` branch and the cherry-picked commit on the `qa` branch. This is why your pull request doesn't display the message "There is nothing to compare", because both branches did introduce some changes that, even though look the same, are identified by two different commits (with different SHA1s) that need to be merged.

This behavior also explains why your pull request's preview looks as if `qa` hasn't registered the cherry-picked commit. The pull request is actually showing you the set of changes detected from the merge basis; and since both branches introduced a change that looks exactly the same, when they're displayed they appear as a single change.

Comment: Actually there is no conflict occurring, are you mentioning some thing as conflict here ?

Comment: `Now If I raise PR from dev to qa , My expectation is that it should display the message "There is nothing to compare", but it is showing the files modified/added during the commit e105xfb as files changed.`

The way how it was phrased made me think that you were expecting no changes between the two branches, but some conflicts have arisen during the merge, which would be plausible since `dev` and `qa` are just a commit away (e105xfb), the one you cherry-picked into `qa`.

Comment: Oh No sir. It doesn't throw any conflicts but it is showing the already  pushed changes , the changes pushed as part of cherry-pick in the PR.

Comment: @ThomasRaj I've updated my answer